# Pandas profiling correlation warning seems to be wrong

Tags: pandas, pandas-profiling

I'm working on this dateset:

```
https://www.kaggle.com/ronitf/heart-disease-uci?select=heart.csv
```

I'm viewing the results of `pandas profiling` and it suggests that `age` column has `HIGH CORRELATION` with `thalach` column.

I checked the 3 types of correlation between those fields:

```
print(f"pearson = ",df['age'].corr(df['thalach'], method='pearson'))
print(f"spearman = ",df['age'].corr(df['thalach'], method='spearman'))
print(f"kendall = ",df['age'].corr(df['thalach'], method='kendall'))
```

And I'm getting:

```
pearson =  -0.39852193812106734
spearman =  -0.3980524371044455
kendall =  -0.28000884141748783
```

The 3 types of correlation shows lower correlation.

What am I missing ? Is there a way pandas profiling is wrong ?

Comment: What are the threshold values in `.../site_packages/pandas_profiling/config_default.yaml` file? (around 80th line)

Comment: Is there a way to print this value from jupter ?

Comment: Not sure; you can find this file in the installed packages in your system, did that work out?